# angular processing a json object compiling but throwing a error

Tags: angular, typescript, http

I have the following component in a angular6 project.

```
export class BoxdataComponent implements OnInit {
  numberOnSite: Object;
  number: number;
  numberClicks: Object;
  constructor(private _pullAnalyticsService: PullanaliticsService) {}

  ngOnInit() {
    timer(0, 5000).pipe(
      switchMap( _ => this._pullAnalyticsService.httpGetAsync()
    )).pipe(
      map(ret => {
        console.log(ret.ListOfData[0]); // ListOfData[0]);
        console.log(ret.ListOfData[1]);
        this.numberOnSite = ret.ListOfData[0];
        this.numberClicks = ret.ListOfData[1];
      })
    ).subscribe();
  }
```

}

where the `httpGetAsync()` is defined in a service as.

```
  httpGetAsync() {
      return this.httpClient.get(this.theUrl);
  }
```

Now this is working fine I see the correct data in the console and numberOnSite and numberClicks are the correct value.  But I am getting the error:

```
ERROR in src/app/boxdata/boxdata.component.ts(22,25): error TS2339: Property 'ListOfData' does not exist on type 'Object'.
src/app/boxdata/boxdata.component.ts(23,25): error TS2339: Property 'ListOfData' does not exist on type 'Object'.
src/app/boxdata/boxdata.component.ts(24,33): error TS2339: Property 'ListOfData' does not exist on type 'Object'.
src/app/boxdata/boxdata.component.ts(25,33): error TS2339: Property 'ListOfData' does not exist on type 'Object'.
```

Note: `ret` is a json object.

Defined as:

```
{"ListOfData": [  4467 , 4065 ]}
```

These errors are thrown after the project successfully refreshes.  Also if I stop the project with ctrl-C and run `ng serve` the project will no longer "compile."  However if I remove the problematic lines, run `ng serve` then change them back again it works.  Why is the project doing this?  I am on vs code if that has anything to do with it.  Thx.

Comment: Change the pipe line to `map(ret:any => {`instead. It is a compilation error being caused by type checking, as `ret` is being treated as type `Object`, which does not have a `ListOfData` property. By typing `ret:any`, we're removing the type checking, and saying it may have any properties

Comment: I think this will work @user184994 but now I think i need a comma somewhere Im getting `ERROR in src/app/boxdata/boxdata.component.ts(21,14): error TS1005: ',' expected` where does the comma go (sorry I just started learning angular 3 days ago).

Comment: Hard to say without seeing your code, but the error is on line 21 if that helps? What is the code from that line?

Comment: oh yea did not see I did not post the line numbers its the       `map(ret: any => {` line that used to be `map( ret => {`

Comment: Sorry, my bad, change it to `map((ret:any) => {` with brackets

Comment: works  you can post your answer so I can except it.  @user184994

Comment: No probs, I've added that, thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Change the pipe line to

```
map((ret:any) => {
```

It is a compilation error being caused by type checking, as `ret` is being treated as type Object, which does not have a ListOfData property.

By typing `ret:any`, we're removing the type checking, and saying it may have any properties

Answer (score 0):

Please remove "Object" declared variable let's declare like this

numberOnSite:any; //if your variable array use like this any[]=[]:
numberClicks:any;